# Undo the new merge request in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I have pushed a commit by mistake to my Gitlab. How can I undo it?

[image: see image]

Comment: Search function helps you a lot ;) [Answer by rednaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits)

Answer (score 7):

**Easy way is to click the `revert` button in the merged merge request.**

[Click for Reference docs](https://code.cognizant.com/help/user/project/merge_requests/revert_changes.md)

**Steps to revert a merge request from UI:**

1. Click revert button
   This creates a new branch `rever-some_sha`.2
2. Either opt for a new merge request and submit that.

[ Or ]

1. Checkout to `revert-some_sha` locally, add any changes you wanted.
2. Create a merge request and click merge to master.

**Recommendation:** Do a periodical `rebase` of your branch to be on top of master. Which avoids any conflicts and helps to catch any failing tests before even merging your branch.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to revert a MR:
"Sorry, we cannot revert this merge request automatically. This merge request may already have been reverted, or a more recent commit may have updated some of its content."  Does this mean I have to create a new MR manually the changes everything back?

Comment: I have another MR that I'm trying to revert (that's not as old as the one I'm referring to in the above comment) and I'm getting a "Deadline Exceeded" message.  What does that mean?

Comment: @HisDivineShadow Bit confusing. 
MR1 you pushed and when you try to revert, you have got `Sorry, we cannot revret....`. Then you have another MR2 to revert, which threw `Deadline Exceeds`. Correct me if I am wrong.  If this the case, ask all the people to stop who are pushing to this master branch. Check the commit tree or use `source tree`. cherry pick the commits to revert or reset. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572096/how-do-cherry-pick-and-revert-work

Comment: @HisDivineShadow You have to do it manually locally, before you push anything to remote. As I assume, your remote is already messed up and you shouldn't be over complicating it.

Comment: I should maybe have been a little more clear.  The MR page has a Revert button on it.  For both of the cases above I got those errors, I just wanted to know what they meant.  I eventually created new local branches and used the `git revert` command to revert the commits then pushed the changes and created new Merge Requests,

Comment: Interesting. Usually it creates a new branch to allow the revert as a revert commit. But, if you delayed or already there are incoming commits then you might see the error 1 that you mentioned and prompts to perform manual revert. 
 
I am unaware of the second error. Sorry.

Comment: Note that revert does not "go backwards"! You are *not* undoing commits with `revert`. Revert applies more commits on top to put back the effect of the previous commit.

Answer (score 1):

I quote rednaw:

> You can revert commits with git revert . This will create
>   a new commit which reverts the changes of the commit you specified
>   with the .
>
> Note that you only revert that specific commit, and not commits after
>   that. If you want to revert a range of commits, you can do it like
>   this:
>
> ```
> git revert <oldest_commit_hash>..<latest_commit_hash>
> ```
>
> Just note that this command is a little bit funny. It actually doesn't
>   revert the commit specified with  itself, but the
>   commits after that until and including .
>
> Look at the git-revert man page for more information about the git
>   revert command. Also look at this answer for more information about
>   reverting commits.
>
> Note that this revert command also deletes the corresponding local
>   files

Comment: I made the revert in my local project but in gitlab the button create merge request does not disappear

Answer (score -3):

Assuming that you mistakenly created a merge request on Gitlab,
All you have to do is scroll to the bottom of the merge request page and click on the
button **close merge request**