# How does 'git cherry-pick' find the file(s) to apply the changes to?

Tags: git, commit, git-cherry-pick

I have two repositories with a similar structure, but no common commits. I've added them as remotes of each other to be able to [`cherry-pick`](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) commits between them.

Recently, I've noticed that git correctly applies the commit's changes even if the files' paths in the repositories differ (and the files themselves differ). How does `git` find the file(s) to apply the changes to? Does it look through *all* the files in the current snapshot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do cherry-pick and revert work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572096/how-do-cherry-pick-and-revert-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [phd's suggested duplicate, How do cherry-pick and revert work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572096/how-do-cherry-pick-and-revert-work?noredirect=1&lq=1) as cherry-pick really does use `git merge`.

Note that `git merge` runs `git diff --find-renames` (well, the internal equivalent of it anyway).  This is the step that discovers which files are renamed from which other files.  To see how *that* works, see my answers to [Trying to understand `git diff` and `git mv` rename detection mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46256139/1256452) and [Git Diff of same files in two directories always result in "renamed"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40351574/1256452).  The rename-detector is run on *both* diffs:

- `git diff parent child`, where *child* is the commit being cherry-picked and *parent* is its parent; and
- `git diff parent HEAD`, which finds the changes on "our" side of the merge operation.  Note that *`parent`* here is the parent commit of the commit being cherry-picked, not the parent of `HEAD` itself.

Typically, the parent-vs-child has few renames to find (most people don't cherry-pick a massive-rename operation), but the parent-vs-`HEAD` may have a large number of renames to detect.

Answer (score 0):

`git cherry-pick eacf32b` will take the *patch* which describes commit `eacf32b`, and try to apply it on top of your current commit.

So yes : if looks through all the files in the "snapshot" described by the cherry picked commit.

---

A more complete answer is : `git cherry-pick` does a merge-like operation to apply the patch.

Starting from :

```
--*--*--A--B--C--D
         \
          \
           D--E--F <- HEAD
```

If you run `git cherry-pick D`, it will apply a merge-like operation, using `C` as the "base content", `D` as "theirs" and `F` as "ours", as if you were merging something with the following history to build `D'` :

```
..*..*..A..B   C--D
         .      \  .
          .      \  .
           D..E   F..D'
```

So `git` also looks at the diff between `C` and `F`, and may detect file renaming or trigger conflicts when applying the patch `C..D` on top of `C..F`

Comment: It' can't be `the "snapshot" described by the cherry picked commit` because, as I mentioned, the paths of the corresponding files may differ and `cherry-pick` would still work.